# Find the equivalence class of 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

R is a relation defined on the integers by $(a,b) \in R$ is $a^2-b^2$ and is divisible by 3.

I set a or b to zero to get all the negative and positive values in the equivalence class. Although I want to say it is $(...,-9n,-6n,3n,0,3n,6n,9n,...)$ for some integer n. But I do not think this is correct because if n = 1, 6n does not belong to the relation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $a=3n,b=3m$ and if $a=3n\pm1, b=3m\pm1$

Answer (score 1):

We have your equivalence relation **R** as $a \sim b$ if $3|(a^2 - b^2)$.

To find the class of elements equivalent to $0$, we need to set one of the elements to $0$ (just one because of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity, as this is an equivalence relation): suppose $a \sim 0$, i.e. $3|(a^2 - 0^2) \Longrightarrow 3|a^2$. Then by [Euclid's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), $3|a$. So the equivalence class of $0$ is the set of all integers that we can divide by $3$, i.e. that are multiples of $3: \{\ldots, -6,-3,0,3,6, \ldots\}$.

Answer (score -1):

The set has the following equivalence relations.
[image: [0] equivalence relation on set]